# Java JCombobox and JButton issue

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I'm currently working on a project for my computer science class and I'm having a problem. I have multiple buttons and 2 comboboxes and I want them all to work independently of each other. Unfortunately, whenever I press a button it works as a "select" button and activates whatever is currently selected in the combobox! How would I be able to solve this? A snippet of my code is below

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  // Sound Menu
  String soundSelect = (String)soundBox.getSelectedItem();
  int soundIndex = soundBox.getSelectedIndex();
    switch (soundIndex){
      case 0:
        stopClip(meowSong);
        stopClip(meowRemix);
        ImageIcon catDel = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("tres-quatro.png"));
        delEvent.setIcon(catDel);
        ImageIcon catAdd = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("im-hungry.png"));
        addEvent.setIcon(catAdd);
        break;
      case 1:
        stopClip(meowRemix);
        playMeow(meowSong);
        catDel = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("tres-quatro.png"));
        delEvent.setIcon(catDel);
        catAdd = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("im-hungry.png"));
        addEvent.setIcon(catAdd);
        break;
      case 2:
        stopClip(meowSong);
        playMeow(meowRemix);
        ImageIcon thugCat = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("tres-quatro-thug.png"));
        delEvent.setIcon(thugCat);
        ImageIcon hungryThug = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("im-hungry-thug.png"));
        addEvent.setIcon(hungryThug);
        break;
    }


  // View Menu
    String viewSelect = (String)viewTypes.getSelectedItem();
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("ADD EVENT"))
    {
        playMeow(meowSound);
        createEvent();
      }else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("DELETE EVENT"))
        {
            playMeow(meowSound);
            deleteEvent();
        }else{
          panel.remove(displayMessage2);
          panel.add(displayMessage);
          panel.remove(text);
        }

    int selection = viewTypes.getSelectedIndex();
         switch (selection)
         {
          case 0: displayMessage.setText("Enter the Sunday of the week you'd like to view! DD/MM");
                  panel.add(text);
                  panel.add(enter);
                  String date = text.getText();
                  if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Enter")){
                    weeklyCalendar(calendar.getHashmap(), date);
                    displayMessage.setText("Select a CATlendar view or you can ADD or DELETE an event!");
                    panel.remove(text);
                    panel.remove(enter);
                  }
                  break;
          case 1: displayMessage.setText("Enter the date you'd like to view! DD/MM");
                  panel.add(text);
                  panel.add(enter);
                  date = text.getText();
                  if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Enter")){
                    playMeow(meowSound);
                    dailyCalendar(calendar.getHashmap(), date);
                    displayMessage.setText("Select a CATlendar view or you can ADD or DELETE an event!");
                    panel.remove(text);
                    panel.remove(enter);
                  }
                  break;
        case 2: displayMessage.setText("Press Enter to view monthly");
                panel.remove(text);
                panel.add(enter);
                if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Enter")){
                  monthlyCalendar();
                  displayMessage.setText("Select a CATlendar view or you can ADD or DELETE an event!");
                  panel.remove(enter);
                }
                break;
           }

    panel.revalidate();
    panel.repaint();
    SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(panel).pack();
}
```

Comment: Please consider posting [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> whenever I press a button it works as a "select" button and activates whatever is currently selected in the combobox

Well that is what you ActionListener code does. You always execute the switch statement no matter what component generated the ActionEvent.

Create individual ActionListeners for each component instead of trying to share a single ActionListener for all components. Then the code will be specific for each component and there will be no need for if statements to determine which component generated the event.

Edit:

> How can you have individual actionListeners for each component?

1. You can create an inner class that implements the ActionListener interface

   ```
   comboBox.addActionListener( new MyComboBoxListener() );

   ...

   class MyComboBoxListener implements ActionListener
   {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
       {
           // add your code here
       }
   }
   ```
2. You can use annonymous inner classes

   ```
   comboBox.addActionListenener( new ActionListener()
   {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
       {
           // add your code here
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: I've thought about doing that but I don't know how. How can you have individual actionListeners for each component? Thanks!